# Multiple producer, single consumer situation

Tags: java, multithreading, producer-consumer

I have a task *T* to be run at a fixed rate *R*. I have multiple java programs *P1*, *P2*, etc doing this task independently with different kinds inputs. I want the task to be done at a rate *R* while all programs are running concurrently.
So what I'm looking for is implementing a different program *P*, which solely does the task at rate *T* with inputs from all programs *P1*, *P2*, etc. In other words, *P1*, *P2*, etc generate data, which *P* consumes for performing *T* at rate *R*
What I don't know is how to make a dynamic queue (a LinkedBlockingQueue may be) which can be accessed by different programs.
Ideas?

*PS: If not Java, I can also use C/C++. I'd prefer solutions in Java as the programs are now in Java*

Comment: Are these *threads* executing the task or *processes*? If threads, why do you want a different process?

Answer (score 2):

OK, implement a program that exposes some kind of interface. The simplest interface is reading from socket or even just STDIN. You have to define protocol. For example you can use standard java serialization.

Now all your programs P1, P2 etc will "write" commands into the stream. The program that executes tasks will read them, store in queue and execute in specified order using either your custom implementation, java.util.Timer or Executors.

Deamon thread is irrelevant here. Deamon thread is a thread that does not prevent program from terminating when all other (non deamon) threads has been terminated.

You can implement all this as you described as separate java processes. I just really do not understand why. Did you probably think about using JMS? It will allow you to completely decouple your modules and use the as one process and as separate processes too.

Answer (score 1):

If you actually want a separate *thread*, rather than a separate process, then I'd recommend the following:

- A [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html) with a single thread, that is responsible for executing tasks.
- A [LinkedBlockingQueue](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html) that the other threads add tasks to. It's important to use a blocking queue, even if you give it a high capacity, so that you don't get into a situation where you're producing faster than you're consuming (or, at least, to identify that situation and take whatever steps you need).
- A [Runnable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) that pulls items off the queue and executes them. You'd add this runnable to the threadpool with the `scheduleAtFixedRate()` method.

Comment: Actually I need a separate process. P1, P2, etc are different java programs, and all of these need to do task T (along with their other stuff). And I need task T to be run at a fixed rate, for which I thought I'd use a separate process which just does T. So in your solution, is there someway I can make all processes P1, P2, etc put to the queue, and a different process take from it?